# Find maximum value of a function - wrong output?

Tags: maximum

I want to find the local maximum value of the function:

[image]

where the domain is 0 < x < 3/2.

Wolfram|Alpha gives me the correct answer while Mathematica gives me a totally different answer. Why is that?

Alpha:

-0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] - 0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] +   0.123626 Sin[4 x] maximum 0< x < 3/2

**Local maximum at x = 0.800001**

Mathematica:

```
FindMaximum[{-0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] - 0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 0.123626 Sin[4 x], 0 <= x <= 3/2}, {x}]
```

**Out -> {0.189256, {x -> 1.5}}**

Thank you.

Comment: W|A shows the plot of what it found, and it is clearly wrong; further, from the plot, it's clear what the correct answer would be (1.5). Why do you think it is correct?

Comment: If one plots the second derivative: `Plot[D[f[x1], {x1, 2}] /. x1 -> x, {x, 0.7, 0.9}]` in the interval surrounding the questionable point `x=0.8` one sees that it passes zero in its vicinity. Here `f[x]` is your function. The conclusion is that Alpha has reported you a saddle point, rather than the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = -0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] - 
   0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 0.123626 Sin[4 x];
Reduce[{D[Rationalize[f[x], 0], x] > 0, 0 < x < 3/2}, x] // N
```

> `0. < x < 0.800001 || 0.829999 < x < 1.5`

It means that `f` is increasing in `0. < x < 0.800001` and decreasing in `0.800001<x<0.829999` and increasing in `0.829999 < x < 1.5`.
So `f` obtain its local maximum at `x=0.800001` and  local minimum at `x=0.829999`.

```
f[x_] = -0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] - 
   0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 0.123626 Sin[4 x];
Plot[f[x], {x, .7, .9}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x}, Evaluate@D[f[x], x]]}, Mesh -> {{0}},
  MeshShading -> {Green, Yellow}, Axes -> {False, True}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm kind of confused right now. @Michael E2 says that W|A shows the plot of what it found, and it is wrong but you got the same maximum value 0.800001. Why couldn't I find the max value with help of FindMaximum?

Comment: @Lisa cvgmt shows there is a local maximum near `x=0.8`, something that is not apparent to the eye and I missed. I assumed it was a horizontal tangent/inflection point and not a max. `FindMaximum` takes discrete steps to find ***a*** local maximum, which might be an end point.  Which steps it takes and which max it finds depends on the starting point.  I posted some code in chat that shows the steps it takes: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59795813#59795813

Comment: @Lisa I said the W|A output shows that the max is wrong because it shows that the graph continues to increase after the point.

Answer (score 1):

Plot your function:

```
Plot[ -0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] -0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 0.123626 Sin[4 x], {x, 0, 3 /2}]
```

[image]

Mathematica's solution

```
FindMaximum[{-0.248226 Cos[2 x] - 0.0184829 Cos[4 x] - 0.0594608 Cos[x] Sin[x] +0.123626 Sin[4 x], 0 <= x <= 3/2}, {x}]
(*{0.189256, {x -> 1.5}}*)
```

seems to be correct.

Alpha perhaps calculated the point with `slope=0`

Comment: Indeed, W|A shows the plot with the stationary point highlighted. +1 to you for illustrating a nice approach to such questions, but I don't see why the question was asked if it originated from W|A output.

Comment: @MichelE2 Yes, that's right, I didn't pay attention to that